# Redirect domain, subfolder and URLs from HTTP > HTTPS

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

How do I redirect the following using .htaccess

from:

- http://example.com, and
- http://www.example.com

to:

- **https**://www.example.com/blog/

And at the same time also redirect all pages:

- http://example.com/blog/page-01/, and
- http://www.example.com/blog/page-01/

to:

**https**://www.example.com/blog/page-01/

In short, I'd like to force

- all non-www > www,
- all example.com > example.com/blog/,
- all URLs from http > https

Comment: read this https://make.wordpress.org/support/user-manual/web-publishing/https-for-wordpress/

Comment: Read that. I've changed Wordpress Address and Site address to HTTPS. But my main concern is visitors and external links, I want to force them to all go to `https://www.example.com`, even if they clicked on a `http://www.example.com` from somewhere else.